# Ranked duo queue elo gain/loss?

Tags: league-of-legends

Finally convinced a friend of mine to start ranked, we've been doing duo queue and have gone 5/0. Before this I had played some 20 odd games, starting at ~1.1k elo with her. Because it's her first games her elo gain is very large, she's climbed to 1369 while I'm still beneath 1200.

How is it going to affect her and my own elo gain/loss when we queue together with such a gap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For reference:** 
Any player with less than 10 wins will get a considerable amount of ELO gained, or lost. This usually is ~40, and will eventually diminish to your normal ELO gains/losses you see ~11.

As for duo queuing, if you chose to queue with a large ELO gap, you need to keep a few things in mind:

- You're more likely to be last pick.

Because of the difference in ELO, it's harder to find a suitable team of which you two fit evenly into. The result is the lower player is typically last pick, with the remaining team mates chosen to make up for the gap between your ELOs.

- Your ELO gains/losses are affected

A player whom wins a ranked match and is higher ELO than his opponents will naturally receive *less* ELO after a win. As you would imagine, that player would also lose *more* elo upon receiving a loss.

The same can be said for a player that finds them self on the low end of the match. They would receive *more* for a win, and *less* for a loss.

I highly recommend reading this entire article: [League of Legends ELO Breakdown](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Elo_rating_system)

Comment: So, our ELOs ave averaged when queue giving her a larger risk of elo loss and myself a larger gain?

Comment: Yes. Team's ELOs are averaged. I wouldn't worry as much about ELO gain/loss and focus more in the ability to win. If you find yourself able to win games more often with a person, then you're probably better off just playing with them.